# Can whole line NumpyArrays indexing operations be cythonized?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

In the [Cython documentation under `Efficient Indexing`](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#efficient-indexing), on the `gotcha` part it says that:

> This efficient indexing only affects certain index operations, namely
>   those with exactly `ndim` number of typed integer indices.

Does this mean that operations like

```
f[:, w] = something
```

are not optimized?

Answer (score 2):

It probably meant "optimized [compared to pure Python code]". There are different kinds of slicings and most of them are already really fast in Python, there just is not much you can speed up. For example if you use `f[:,w]` you'll get a view of the array `f`. It involves a bit of overhead because a "view" has to be created but it's really fast already because it (excluding certain advanced indexing operations) just a memoryview.

However what Cython can speed up significantly is: accessing single elements of an array. That is a really inefficient operation in Python code because the element has to be "boxed as Python object" when accessed. Cython can avoid this "boxing", when "exactly ndim number of typed integer indices" are used.

So it's not like `f[:,w]` isn't optimized. **It is already optimized** by numpy. Cython can't improve (much) there.

Comment: `:` is `slice(None)`.  I think cython continues use a python/numpy call, rather than replace it with pure c code.

Comment: Though typed memoryviews support slicing and views.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, they explicitly mention that in the linked tutorial and the reason is "that you can continue using Python objects for sophisticated dynamic slicing etc. just as when the array is not typed." No idea how this relates to memoryviews but I guess they support most array-like slicing operations?